# How to await on ValueChanged?

Tags: dart

Say I have:

```
void main() async{
  Future<void> ValueChanged<int> onPressed; // error
  await onPressed(10); // wanna use something like this
}
```

So, what's the solution now?

Comment: I think you need to read up on async and await, and what ValueChanged<> is for. Your code doesn't make any sense to me. Maybe start with "What problem do you want to solve?" instead of "What compiles?"

Comment: @Eiko See, I have very long project, and sometimes I need those things which doesn't make sense when I put them in `main()` to produce a minimal code, so you probably can't relate to what I am talking about. That's why you may choose to close this post. But I am glad to see you write comment when you downvote, there are others people who only downvote when they don't understand anything without giving a reason. You aren't one of them :)

Comment: `ValueChanged<T>` is a type for a method that is called (i.e. callbacks) - probably at a later point. You don't call that function yourself actively, let alone pass in some value. Awaiting that function that isn't returning a `Future` does basically nothing special, in particular it won't wait for anything. Syntactically the question makes absolutely no sense, something is either a `Future<void>` or a `ValueChanged<int>`.
So `why` and `what` are quite essential questions here. Without providing some context, it's impossible to give some kind of answer (and yours doesn't address the question)

Comment: @Eiko I wanted to `await` on `onPressed`, simple! I knew I could also do `Future<void> Function(int x)` but everyone else can do that, I wanted to share some broader way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own `typedef`:

```
typedef MyValueChanged<P, Q> = Future<Q> Function(P value);
```

And now use it like:

```
void main() async{
  MyValueChanged<int, void> onPressed;
  await onPressed(10); // no errors
}
```